# clang issue: inline function inside another function body in C

Tags: c, macos, clang, inline

It is challenging to port from Linux to OS/X.  I have an inline function embedded inside another function body.  On Linux, gcc happily compiled the code, but on OS/X, clang reports error.

Here is the code snippet,

```
$ cat inline.c
void func() {
        inline int max(int a, int b) { return (a>b) ? a : b; }
        int c = max(11,22);
}
```

On Linux, everything is fine,

```
Linux $ gcc -c inline.c
Linux $$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010
```

However, clang on OS/X complains,

```
OSX $ cc -c inline.c
inline.c:2:38: error: function definition is not allowed here
        inline int max(int a, int b) { return (a>b) ? a : b; }
                                     ^
inline.c:3:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'max' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        int c = max(11,22);
                ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
OSX $ cc --version
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0
```

Is this a gcc "feature" or there is a clang flag to enable this capability?

Comment: How many times do you call `max` in that function in the real code?

Comment: Yes, it is a GCC feature.  [Nested functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html#Nested-Functions) are not standard C.  Clang is within its right to object.  If you want your code to be portable, don't do it.

Comment: And `inline` here makes no sense at all. It is a precious tool if you want to place function definitions in header files such they are visible in several .c files. Everything that is found inside the same .c file can be inlined by the compiler without notice, here it is simply superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

> [**GCC *extensions* not implemented yet**](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#gcc-extensions-not-implemented-yet)
>
> clang does not support [nested functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html); this is a complex feature which is infrequently used, so it is unlikely to be implemented anytime soon.

Just move the `max` out the function and make it `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Here, "inline" means "inline *substitution*", rather than "inline *definition*".

According to [N1570](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html):

> 6 A function declared with an inline function specifier is an inline
>   function. Making a function an inline function suggests that calls to
>   the function be as fast as possible.<sup>138)</sup> The extent to
>   which such suggestions are effective is
>   implementation-defined.<sup>139)</sup>
>
> <sub>138) By using, for example, an alternative to the usual function
>   call mechanism, such as ''inline substitution''. ...</sub>

And you shouldn't define another function in a function definition. Also, use `static inline` instead of `inline` would make your life easier.